# How can I autocomplete the inner element of a list in pycharm ?

Tags: python, pycharm

How can I autocomplete the inner element of a list in pycharm and only the inner element ? Not a mixure of methods of the list and the inner element but only the inner element's methods ?

example:

a = list()

a.append(1)

a[0].___ (I want this to only show methods for integers and not both of integer and list)

Answer (score 1):

You you are using Python 3.6 or newer you should be able to use [variable annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-526-syntax-for-variable-annotations):

```
from typing import List

a: List[int] = []
```

This tells PyCharm that `a` is a list containing *only* integer objects.

*Caveat*: I don't know if the current PyCharm 2016.3 release actually supports PEP 526; the [Early Access Programme release 2016.3](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2016/09/pycharm-2016-3-eap-is-available-with-initial-support-for-python-3-6/) certainly included support but I don't follow the release cycle.

Comment: Maybe you know of a way to do the same thing inside a lambda ?

Comment: @HashWizard: perhaps you need to post a new question about that; 'inside a lambda' is rather vague. Are you passing in the list? Then annotate the arguments of a *function* (as you can't annotate a `lambda`, see [Is it possible to type hint a lambda function?](//stackoverflow.com/q/33833881)).